# Shipping Calculator for Fillable PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am trying to create a fillable PDF for a book order form and I want one of the fields to calculate the cost of shipping and handling. The shipping should be 15% of the cost of the order, if the cost of the order is less than `$300`. If the cost of the order is over `$300`, then the shipping should be `10%`. What I have so far is:

```
var v1 = this.getField("TotalCostofOrder").value; 
if (v1 < 300) event.value = (v1*0.15);    
else event.value = (v1*0.1);
```

It seems to run when the total cost of the order is `< 300`, but not when it is over; however, the numbers that are outputted are wrong.

Comment: I take it "event" is a Shipping Charges field.  Is v1 a numeric type after you assign the getField.value to it?

Comment: This is code I was trying to modify, so "event" must be something left over that I need to modify to match my fields. "S&H" is the field where I am trying to input this code and "TotalCostofOrder" is the field I am trying to calculate the percentages of.

Comment: Looks like you are not sure what "event" is.  You need to know (and let us know).  Usually, "event" is a name people give to an element that was clicked/changed/etc.  You should also explain what the flow is.  Is shipping to be computed when the total cost of order changes?  Or are you trying to calculate shipping if/when the user clicks the shipping field?  Most importantly, what is "event?"

Comment: Your code looks fine assuming you are putting it in the custom calculation tab of the S&H field. It's possible that your calculation is off due to the calculation order being wrong.

Comment: I got the code from https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/conditional-execution, which uses event.field in all the examples of if statements, so I thought it was just a required part of the code